# Bluetooth driver installation failing

Tags: drivers, bluetooth

Hi I'm working on my thesis, model-based testing of IoT protocols.

After updating Ubuntu (20.04LTS, dual boot with encrypted disk), an issue appeared while developing with PyBluez. I could not establish connection between my two Bluetooth dongles anymore (ends up in connection time out - the connection is never established), and I thought that the Ubuntu update might be the only cause to this, after endless debugging. (It worked just fine that day before the update).

```
Start-Date: 2022-07-06  15:28:01
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.88'
Upgrade: libqmi-proxy:amd64 (1.28.6-1~20.04.1, 1.30.4-1~ubuntu20.04.1), gnupg-utils:amd64 (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1, 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2), gpg-wks-client:amd64 (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1, 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2), openssl:amd64 (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.15, 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16), gnupg-l10n:amd64 (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1, 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2), update-notifier-common:amd64 (3.192.30.10, 3.192.30.11), azure-cli:amd64 (2.37.0-1~focal, 2.38.0-1~focal), snapd:amd64 (2.54.3+20.04.1ubuntu0.3, 2.55.5+20.04), ubuntu-advantage-tools:amd64 (27.8~20.04.1, 27.9~20.04.1), libqmi-glib5:amd64 (1.28.6-1~20.04.1, 1.30.4-1~ubuntu20.04.1), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (103.0.5060.53-1, 103.0.5060.114-1), gpg-wks-server:amd64 (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1, 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2), gpg:amd64 (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1, 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2), mainline:amd64 (1.0.15-0~202110201909~ubuntu20.04.1, 1.0.15-0~202204070351~ubuntu20.04.1), isc-dhcp-common:amd64 (4.4.1-2.1ubuntu5.20.04.2, 4.4.1-2.1ubuntu5.20.04.3), dirmngr:amd64 (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1, 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2), firefox-locale-en:amd64 (101.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 102.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), gpgv:amd64 (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1, 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2), libmm-glib0:amd64 (1.16.6-2~20.04.1, 1.18.6-1~ubuntu20.04.1), libmbim-proxy:amd64 (1.24.8-1~20.04, 1.26.2-1~ubuntu20.04.1), libssl-dev:amd64 (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.15, 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16), firefox:amd64 (101.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 102.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), modemmanager:amd64 (1.16.6-2~20.04.1, 1.18.6-1~ubuntu20.04.1), libssl1.1:amd64 (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.15, 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16), libssl1.1:i386 (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.15, 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16), gnupg:amd64 (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1, 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2), isc-dhcp-client:amd64 (4.4.1-2.1ubuntu5.20.04.2, 4.4.1-2.1ubuntu5.20.04.3), libmbim-glib4:amd64 (1.24.8-1~20.04, 1.26.2-1~ubuntu20.04.1), gpg-agent:amd64 (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1, 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2), update-notifier:amd64 (3.192.30.10, 3.192.30.11), gpgconf:amd64 (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1, 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2), gpgsm:amd64 (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1, 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2)
End-Date: 2022-07-06  15:28:55
```

As I was not sure what was the exact reason that caused the issue, and wasn't sure would downgrading to older versions with synaptic break my Ubuntu I gave up on the downgrading.

Among other stuff (which seemed not to be relevant), I tried installing a new Bluetooth driver from Asus ('20200806_LINUX_BT_DRIVER_RTL8761B_COEX_v0202'). However, as the `$ sudo make install INTERFACE=all` did not work due to the following error:

```
/home/marko/Downloads/20200909_LINUX_BT_DRIVER_KERNEL_5.7_COEX_v0202/20200806_LINUX_BT_DRIVER_RTL8761B_COEX_v0202/20200806_LINUX_BT_DRIVER_RTL8761B_COEX_v0202/uart/bluetooth_uart_driver/hci_ldisc.c: In function ‘hci_uart_init’:
/home/marko/Downloads/20200909_LINUX_BT_DRIVER_KERNEL_5.7_COEX_v0202/20200806_LINUX_BT_DRIVER_RTL8761B_COEX_v0202/20200806_LINUX_BT_DRIVER_RTL8761B_COEX_v0202/uart/bluetooth_uart_driver/hci_ldisc.c:1082:16: error: ‘struct tty_ldisc_ops’ has no member named ‘magic’
 1082 |  hci_uart_ldisc.magic = TTY_LDISC_MAGIC;
      |                ^
/home/marko/Downloads/20200909_LINUX_BT_DRIVER_KERNEL_5.7_COEX_v0202/20200806_LINUX_BT_DRIVER_RTL8761B_COEX_v0202/20200806_LINUX_BT_DRIVER_RTL8761B_COEX_v0202/uart/bluetooth_uart_driver/hci_ldisc.c:1082:25: error: ‘TTY_LDISC_MAGIC’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘TTY_LDISC_HALTED’?
 1082 |  hci_uart_ldisc.magic = TTY_LDISC_MAGIC;
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                         TTY_LDISC_HALTED
/home/marko/Downloads/20200909_LINUX_BT_DRIVER_KERNEL_5.7_COEX_v0202/20200806_LINUX_BT_DRIVER_RTL8761B_COEX_v0202/20200806_LINUX_BT_DRIVER_RTL8761B_COEX_v0202/uart/bluetooth_uart_driver/hci_ldisc.c:1082:25: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/home/marko/Downloads/20200909_LINUX_BT_DRIVER_KERNEL_5.7_COEX_v0202/20200806_LINUX_BT_DRIVER_RTL8761B_COEX_v0202/20200806_LINUX_BT_DRIVER_RTL8761B_COEX_v0202/uart/bluetooth_uart_driver/hci_ldisc.c:1086:22: error: assignment to ‘ssize_t (*)(struct tty_struct *, struct file *, unsigned char *, size_t,  void **, long unsigned int)’ {aka ‘long int (*)(struct tty_struct *, struct file *, unsigned char *, long unsigned int,  void **, long unsigned int)’} from incompatible pointer type ‘ssize_t (*)(struct tty_struct *, struct file *, unsigned char *, size_t)’ {aka ‘long int (*)(struct tty_struct *, struct file *, unsigned char *, long unsigned int)’} [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
 1086 |  hci_uart_ldisc.read = hci_uart_tty_read;
      |                      ^
```

I decided to go with `$ sudo make install INTERFACE=usb`. After that, my Laptop's Bluetooth Adapter seems not to be found, and with it, the Bluetooth does not work. When I use external Bluetooth dongles, they are found, and used by default (when plugged in). I've tried another driver, the same situation occurs, even though it is not the exact same error (during installation).

Now, I'm guessing that the `$ sudo make install INTERFACE=all` would allow the Laptop's Bluetooth adapter to work, however, I can't get the installation working as you have seen in the previous screenshot.

1. My first question is how to get the laptop Bluetooth adapter working again?
2. My second question is, is there any Bluetooth related dependency in the update log in the first screenshot? If yes, how do I fix it?

Reinstalling Ubuntu is the last option.

I would be very grateful if we could get this solved. I'm stuck on the issue for 3 days already.

Here is more information from the terminal:

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Lenovo QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:0827]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
```

**UPDATE**

The first issue has been resolved by uninstalling the additional drivers, as proposed by the comment below.

The cause of the second issue is still unknown.

```
$ hcitool lecc --random 04:42:1A:57:16:91
Could not create connection: Connection timed out
```

This would not happen before the Ubuntu update. None of the other commands seem to be impacted.

I understand that this is a different area of knowledge, but I'm suspicious if the Ubuntu update could have cause the break down.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. It is unclear now what BT device you are using, why did you have to install some drivers for it, etc. The make log shows that the driver is incompatible with the kernel you are using.

Comment: It is unclear why you are trying to install some Realtek driver, when `lsusb` shows that you have a QCA BT device.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install any drivers for your `[0cf3:e300]` device. it is natively supported by Linux kernel.

Your error log shows that the driver didn't build because it is incompatible with your kernel.

You need to uninstall that driver, because it could blacklist the in-tree module or do something else. Don't ask "how to uninstall it", because we don't know what is that driver, and what that driver does when installed.

Comment: Thanks. Uninstalling the additional drivers made the Bluetooth adapter work again.